# TFDSQliteBackup android delphi xe7

Tags: android, delphi, firedac

Estou tentando fazer *backup* da minha aplicação Android, aplicação feita em Delphi. Estou utilizando o componente `TFDSQliteBackup` com o seguinte código, ele executa e cria o arquivo, mas o arquivo esta em branco alguém sabe como proceder??

```
try
  try
    DataModule1.FDConnection1.Close;
    DataModule1.backup.DestDatabase:= '/storage/sdcard0/tedesco.controlefinanceiro.SQLITE3';
    DataModule1.backup.Backup;
  except
    on e:Exception do
    begin
      ToastMessage(e.Message);
    end;
  end;
finally
   ToastMessage('Backup Concluido');
end;
```

Comment: não gera nenhuma exceção?

Comment: da error: unable to open database